# UI is not updated from Component

Tags: c#, blazor

I would like to use component for some part of code.

Blazor REPL with described issue: https://blazorrepl.com/repl/Gvafwnvx02zDmyvw55
[image: ui]

```
First model:
@foreach(var car in model.Cars)
{
<div>
@*------Here, it works as expected-----------*@
    @car.Name
    <button @onclick="()=> model.RemoveCar(car)" type="button">Remove Car from List</button>
</div>
}

Second model (in component):
@foreach(var car in model.Cars)
{
@*------Here, the deletion does not reflect in UI-----------*@
<CarComponent Model="model2" Car="car"/>
}

@code {
MainModel model = new MainModel();
MainModel model2 = new MainModel();
}
```

The same code with car removing button is also in `CarComponent`. When I click the button from First model, it removes the car. **But from within component, it does not.**

Here are the models with simple remove logic:

```cs
    public class MainModel
    {
        public MainModel()
        {
            Cars.Add(new Car(){Name="Fast one"});
            Cars.Add(new Car(){Name="Slow one"});
        }
        public string Name{get;set;} = "MainModel Name";
        public List<Car> Cars {get;set;} = new List<Car>();
        public void RemoveCar(Car car)
        {
                Cars.Remove(car);
        }
    }
    public class Car
    {
        public string Name{get;set;}
    }
```

`CarComponent`:

```
<div>
    @Car.Name
    <button @onclick="()=> {Model.RemoveCar(Car);StateHasChanged();}" type="button">Remove Car from List</button>
</div>

@code{
[Parameter] public Car Car {get;set;}
[Parameter] public MainModel Model {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- The `StateHasChanged` method re-renders the component on which it was called and all child components, but does not propagate upwards to parent components. Instead, you want to use two-way data binding if you want a child component to update a property on the parent component, notifying the parent component of the change via an event.
- The car you pass is from `model.Cars`, which you try to remove from `model2.Cars`. Since there is no such car in `model2.Cars`, nothing will be deleted.

To resolve, first change the loop to iterate through `model2.Cars`:

```cs
@foreach(var car in model2.Cars)
```

Create an event in the CarComponent that's triggered whenever the model is updated, so that the parent can listen to it and update accordingly:

```cs
[Parameter] public EventCallback<MainModel> ModelChanged { get; set; }
```

Instead of re-rendering the component, call this event when you change the model:

```html
<button @onclick="()=> {Model.RemoveCar(Car);ModelChanged.InvokeAsync(Model);}" type="button">Remove Car from List</button>
```

Instead of a one-way parameter in the parent component, create a two-way binding so that updates in the child propagate to the parent:

```html
<CarComponent @bind-Model="model2" Car="car"/>
```

Note that it would be better practice to remove the responsibility of handling the car list from the car component, and instead leave that to the parent. This can be accomplished by creating a `OnRemove` event in the `CarComponent`, and removing the car from the list on the parent as a response to that event being triggered.

Comment: The first "issue" was just my inadvertence. I do understand now what is going on (StateHasChanged updates only child components). It looks really like a bad practice in this simple example and probably is in the real one too. Because now, I have to add Invoking to every action that changes collection. The two-way binding here is just complicated way how to tell parent component that something has changed, because it does not change the model at all, it is still the same reference, isn't it?

Comment: Since it's a property and not a field, you could introduce a backing field, and in the setter call ModelChanged.InvokeAsync alongside updating the backing field. Other than that, as mentioned in the answer, it's better to simply not have the responsibility of maintaining a collection within the CarComponent, and you should just notify the parent component of requested actions via an event and carry them out there.